# Replace URL query string with slash for a cleaner URL

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have created a new content type with a body and multiple fields.

I use the following query string

```
?article=referral-partners
```

to change the content of the node's body according to the value of the value of article.

The full URL looks like this (with my path alias I created):

```
http://localhost/userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide?article=referral-partners
```

I would like to clean up the url to look like this instead:

```
http://localhost/userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide/article/referral-partners
```

How can I do this with Drupal 7?

Comment: Where is the ?article=referral-partners coming from?

Comment: My own custom block is generating it.

Comment: Okay, so you're looking for "How can I use the cleaned up URL" rather than how to clean up the URL?

Comment: uh yeah I guess that would be a better formed question sorry. I can generate my links in a cleaned form no problem, but how will I get that cleaned form as php variables?

Comment: I think you can add a URL alias for userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide?article=referral-partners to points to userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide/article/referral-partners try it out here: admin/config/search/path/add

Comment: No that gives me an error: "The path 'userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide?article=referral-partners' is either invalid or you do not have access to it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a chance your URL is going to change a lot as far as "depth" goes, you can use [arg()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) to access any element in the path.

If your path is `userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide/article/referral-partners`, you would use something like this...

```
$article = arg(4);     // $article is set to 'referral-partners'
```

... and then just check the value of $article.  If the code can potentially be run on nodes or pages you don't want it to, then you'd also probably want to check other "args" for safety.  Generally Drupal will let you tack on all kinds of extra path elements without needing to go through extra hoops as long as the initial path is a real one.

Comment: I had to use subautopath module to get it to work on alias URLs as well. But this is the approach I took. Thanks.

Edit: Does drupal filter/sanitize this already?

Comment: No sanitation involved in the function;  it really just runs explode() on the path and then uses caching (`drupal_static()`) to avoid having to run explode() every time it's called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this on your custom module for the redirects with the query strings.

```
/*
 * custom redirect with query string
 * module implements hook_init()
 */

function MyModule_init() {
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide/article/referral-partners') {
    drupal_goto('userguides/contacts/my-first-user-guide', array('query' => array('article' => 'referral-partners')));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using the module [Subpathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto)

Instead of using query parameters like this:
    ?article=referral-partners
I just use them like this
    /my-arg-i-want
and I am able to get them in my module using arg(2).